# me gustaria ver como solucionar el error en discord.js V14 el error no se en que parte del codigo se encuentran, ademas de ser un poco novato en esto

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (
  !message.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)
) {
  return message.reply('I do not have permission to manage roles.');
}

try {
  await message.member.roles.add(role);

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Verification Successful')
    .setDescription(`You have been granted the ${role.name} role.`)
    .toJSON();

  const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('verifyButton')
        .setLabel('Verify')
        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
        .setDisabled(true)
        .toJSON()
    );

  message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.reply('There was an error while trying to grant the role.');
  }
},

  async interactionRun(interaction) {
    const role = interaction.options.getRole("role");

    if (!role) {
      return interaction.reply('Please specify a role.');
    }

  if (
  !interaction.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)
  ) {
    return interaction.reply('I do not have permission to manage roles.');
  }
```

El error es este

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')
    at Object.interactionRun (C:\Users\TyouDm\Downloads\discord-js-bot-main\discord-js-bot-main\src\commands\utility\verify.js:72:31)
    at Object.handleSlashCommand (C:\Users\TyouDm\Downloads\discord-js-bot-main\discord-js-bot-main\src\handlers\command.js:140:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async module.exports (C:\Users\TyouDm\Downloads\discord-js-bot-main\discord-js-bot-main\src\events\interactions\interactionCreate.js:18:5)
```

Esta en `discord.js` V14 el error pasa solamente cuando el comando es ejecutado, no al momento de prenderlo, ademas de no saber en que parte del código se encuentra el error(Soy un poco principiante en lo que se basa `discord.js`)

Este es un comando de verify, pero les deje la parte que supongo que da error. como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Debes asegurarte en declarar la variable `message`, cuando tu aplicación esta conectada esa variable no debería darte problemas.

Comment: El error está aquí: ```interaction.guild.me.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)```. La propiedad ```iteraction.guild.me``` es ```undefined```. Deberías poner también el código de "handlers/commands.js".

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js v14 utiliza PermissionsBitField.

const {PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
message.guild.members.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageRoles)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).